# Наибольшее произведение-палиндром

Tags: c#, linq

Число-палиндром с обеих сторон (справа налево и слева направо) читается одинаково. Самое большое число-палиндром, полученное умножением двух двузначных чисел – 9009 = 91 × 99.

Найдите самый большой палиндром, полученный умножением двух трехзначных чисел.

Я решил эту задачу с использованием LINQ.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Queue <int> palindrom = new Queue <int>();
        Queue <int> first_num = new Queue<int>();
        Queue <int> second_num = new Queue<int>();


        for (int a = 999; a > 100; a--)
        {
            for (int b = 999; b > 100; b--)
            {
                int c = a * b;
                string s = c.ToString();
                string reverse_s = Reverse(s);
                if (s == reverse_s)
                { 
                    first_num.Enqueue(a);
                    second_num.Enqueue(b);
                    palindrom.Enqueue(c);
                }

            }
        }

        int max = 0;
        int f_num = 0;
        int s_num = 0;

        int n = 0;

        foreach (int p in palindrom)
        {
            if (max < p)
            {
                max = p;
                f_num = first_num.ElementAt<int>(n);
                s_num = second_num.ElementAt<int>(n);
            }
            n++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Самый большой палиндром : {max}, получен умножением {f_num} на {s_num}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
```

Код рабочий и работает правильно.

Но я бы хотел решить его без использования LINQ. И кроме того, в списке "palindrom" храниться по 2 одинаковых палиндрома так как 993*913 и 913*993 - это одно и тоже. Надо удалить эти копии вместе с элементами копии в стеках "first_num" и "second_num".

Comment: Если во втором цикле идти не до 100, а до `а`, то повторов не будет

Comment: Спасибо, да вы полностью правы!, просто на моем примере я сам хотел записать все палиндромы, чтобы если надо вывести их все на экран.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без использования Linq

```
var max = 0;
var firstValue = 0;
var secondValue = 0;

for (var i = 100; i < 999; i++)
{
    for (var j = 100; j < 999; j++)
    {
        var multiplication = i * j;
        if (Reverse(multiplication.ToString()) == multiplication.ToString())
        {
            if (max < multiplication)
            {
                max = multiplication;
                firstValue = i;
                secondValue = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Самый большой палиндром : {max}, получен умножением {firstValue} на {secondValue}");

Console.ReadKey();
```